# Extracting 2 groups of numbers from string in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have an attribute field that contains strings like "iuyluf45567kjyyr347fklj". All strings contain various amount of characters and digits (there is no clear pattern) but each string contains 2 groups of numbers. I have to extract those numbers as new attributes. I managed to extract first number using Field Calculator:
 `regexp_substr('iuyluf45567kjyyr347fklj', '(\\d+)')` gives me 45567.
But I have no idea how to extract the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
regexp_substr('iuyluf45567kjyyr347fklj', '(\\d+)[^\\d]*$')
```

It will look for one or more digit that does not contain another digit between it and the end of the string