# Extract numbers from mixed string (numbers & text) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, string, decimal-points

In QGIS 3.18. There are several similar questions such as [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332944/extracting-2-groups-of-numbers-from-string-in-qgis-field-calculator) which do not address my exact problem.

I have an attribute of comma-concatenated values containing text and numbers. I would like to extract all of the numbers as they are in that list, retaining the commas -- or, said differently, remove everything that is not an integer, a period (as I wish to include decimal values) or a comma. (I then wish to retain only the *largest* of those numbers, but that might be a separate question.)

I have attempted variations of the expression in the above-linked question, `regexp_substr("My data", '(\\d+)[^\\d]*$')`, with the results in the table below; it seems decimals are not considered digits, and it doesn't seem to be taking more than one number in any case:

As an example :

| My data | Desired output | Output with the above expression |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.50 | 1.50 | 50 |
| 0.30 (BRGM) | 0.30 | 30 |
| 1.28 (bassin),1.53 (pré) | 1.28,1.53 | 53 |
| NR | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Hi @Ian Turton, thanks for the fix. Any idea what I'm doing wrong for the formatting?

Comment: you needed a blank line above the table (not sure why it worked in preview though)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like `([\d.,]+)[^\d.,]*` will work. I don't know how `regexp_substr` handles multiple capture groups so you might need to wrap that regexp in a custom function to get exactly your required output.

Comment: I'm learning about custom functions now! Will report back.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Ian's answer one way to get around multiple capturing groups is to convert your comma-separated attributes to an array (if they will always come in that format) with `string_to_array()`, run Ian's `regexp_substr()` expression on each item using `array_foreach()`, then convert the resulting array back to a string with `array_to_string()`.

Something like

`nullif(array_to_string(array_foreach(string_to_array("my_data",','),
regexp_substr(@element,'([\\d.]+)[^\\d.]*')),','),'')`

You can even perform additional functions on each array item with additional functions wrapped in the second parameter of `array_foreach()`, such as `try(to_real())` to convert the text that results from the regex (e.g. `'1.50'`) to an actual number (i.e. `1.50`) and then perform mathematical operations. Or you can append additional text to each item in the array, etc.

---

Alternatively you can also use `regexp_replace()` to strip out all characters that are not digits, full stops or commas.

`nullif(regexp_replace("my_data",'[^\\d.,]',''),'')`